# How to make google to point in results to subdirectory?

Tags: web, subdirectory

For most keywords google search results point to main page of my website (like example.com). But I would prefer google to point to pages with stuff specific for the keyword (i.e. keyword "product1" pointed to example.com/product1.html). Pages for specific products are well optimized for the adequate keywords, but results point to main page.

Is it any way to change that?

**UPDATE:**

My site is about window blinds. I've got main page that contains a general information (i.e. example.com) and many other pages that contain specific information (i.e. example.com/roller_blimds.html). If someone types "roller blinds" in google search box at this moment in results there is link to main page (example.com), and I would prefer it was a link to file connected to rollers: example.com/roller_blinds.html.

Comment: This is not really programmation oriented, but you can look at google tools for webmasters : https://www.google.com/webmasters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got your point correctly, but here's some help.

First of all i would like you to try search for Paraleb on google.
This is my own website, and here's the search result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/obXGL.png

As you can see it has the main domain/directory paraleb.com listed at the top, and below it there are subpages, like About, Clients, Contact us, Work.

What i did here is not that hard, i just used metatags on all pages, but make sure to use different keywords and description for each page.
*(ex: in the html code of the contact us/or your product's page, but the meta description, a breif description about your product, its title, and the relevant keywords).*

**Helpful meta-tags i'm using:**

```
    <title>Paraleb | Creative Digital Agency</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Creative Digital Agency">

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@paraleb">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Home">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Creative Digital Agency">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@Paraleb"> 
<meta name="twitter:image" content="/static/img/social/twitter_360.png">     
        <meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />     
    <meta property="og:image" content="/static/img/social/facebook_og_720.png" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Creative Digital Agency" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Paraleb" />
```